# How to connect to an Oracle database installed on a Windows 11 virtual machine (Parallels) using a computer with Apple Silicon (M1)?

Tags: oracle, datagrip, parallels, apple-silicon, instantclient

Since Oracle Database cannot be installed on Apple Silicon, I decided to take a workaround, but now I do not understand how to connect to the Oracle Database, which I installed on a Windows 11 virtual machine through Parallels.

I understand that this makes little sense, since in fact you can use Oracle from Windows 11 and do whatever you want with it.

But as an experiment, I wanted to try connecting to an already deployed HR database in my Windows 11 virtual machine using DataGrip on my Apple Silicon (M1) computer.

I know that there are other ways to use Oracle on a Mac (using Docker for example) but maybe we can come up with some other alternative, or maybe there already is, but I don't know about it.

I hope I wrote as clear as possible. Sorry, I'm using a translator.

[I used this instruction](https://developers.ascendcorp.com/how-to-install-oracle-instant-client-on-apple-silicon-m1-24b67f2dc743) to install Instant Client (as I understand it, this tool helps us connect to the Database server, be it a virtual machine or a remote server), I spent several hours installing everything. In Datagrip, when connecting, I specified different settings, wrote the path to the installed instantclient, however, I constantly get an error when connecting (whatever settings I choose), I googled this error, but I still did not understand how I can apply them It is for M1 and not Windows computers.

**The error looked like this:**

*Failed DBMS: Oracle (no ver.)  Case sensitivity: plain=mixed, delimited=exact Native library cannot be loaded.  no ocijdbc21 in java.library.path: /Users/malkhaz/instantclient_19_8:/Users/malkhaz/lib:/Users/malkhaz/instantclient_19_8.*

Comment: instantclient_19_8 on Apple M1 works perfectly here, what's strange its that on your machine it's looking for ocijdbc21 instead of the installed ocijdbc19, looks like you are trying to run from the one installed in the Windows VM but from the Mac terminal.

Comment: it looks like you need to change JDBC driver to 19.8 or 19.3 for proper OCI connection. 
Have you tried Thin connection?